# One way ANOVA in R given Mean, SD, sample size only?

Tags: r, anova

I am trying to run a one way ANOVA on some data. One factor, 4 levels. I only have mean, SD, and sample sizes to work with. Is there a way to do this in R?

Comment: If you have the sd's then you have the variances. You don't, however, have the variance of the total group, which would be necessary to give a correct answer. (This is actually not a coding question.)

Comment: By "sample sizes", do you mean that you have $n_j$ for each level of the factor? Also, can you clarify "mean, SD"? Do you have the marginal (total) mean & SD, the means & SDs for each level, or both?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but an answer at the linked duplicate gives a strategy that works in any package. R also has some packages that can work with summary data, but the approach given at the link is so fast and simple to do in R that it's hardly worth looking for them.

Comment: Briefly, for each group, generate a random sample of the relevant size (the distribution doesn't actually matter for obtaining estimates and p-values and such). Standardize it to mean 0 var 1 (`scale` in R), multiply by the group std deviation, add the group mean. Conduct ANOVA as usual. (Don't bother with diagnostics, naturally.)